# In C++11 is sqrt defined as constexpr?

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr

In C++11 is `std::sqrt` defined as `constexpr`, i.e. can it legally be used from other `constexpr` functions or in compile-time contexts like array sizes or template arguments? g++ seems to allow it (using `-std=c++0x`), but I'm not sure I can take that as authoritative given that c++0x/c++11 support is still incomplete. The fact that I can't seem to find anything on the Internet makes me unsure.

It seems like this should be something one could easily find out using Google, but I've tried (for 40 minutes now...) and couldn't find anything. I could find several proposals for adding constexpr to various parts of the standard library (like for example [this one](http://www.open-std.org/Jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2976.html)), but nothing about `sqrt` or other math functions.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`std::sqrt` is not defined as `constexpr`, according to section 26.8 of N3291: the C++11 FDIS (and I doubt they added it to the final standard after that). One could possibly write such a version, but the standard library version is not `constexpr`.

Comment: Is this stated there explicitly? 26.8 C library makes no reference to constexpr. An implementation would surely still be conformant if it provided constexpr function implementations in addition to those mandated without.

Comment: @NicolBolas IIRC adding `constexpr` is not allowed by the standard.

Answer (score 27):

Here is a fast and efficient constexpr implementation for `double` floating point numbers. You may adapt it to `float` too, if needed:

```
#include <limits>   

namespace Detail
{
    double constexpr sqrtNewtonRaphson(double x, double curr, double prev)
    {
        return curr == prev
            ? curr
            : sqrtNewtonRaphson(x, 0.5 * (curr + x / curr), curr);
    }
}

/*
* Constexpr version of the square root
* Return value:
*   - For a finite and non-negative value of "x", returns an approximation for the square root of "x"
*   - Otherwise, returns NaN
*/
double constexpr sqrt(double x)
{
    return x >= 0 && x < std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity()
        ? Detail::sqrtNewtonRaphson(x, x, 0)
        : std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN();
}
```

Answer (score 25):

Just in case anyone is interested in a meta integer square root function, here is one I wrote while a ago:

```
constexpr std::size_t isqrt_impl
    (std::size_t sq, std::size_t dlt, std::size_t value){
    return sq <= value ?
        isqrt_impl(sq+dlt, dlt+2, value) : (dlt >> 1) - 1;
}

constexpr std::size_t isqrt(std::size_t value){
    return isqrt_impl(1, 3, value);
}
```

Comment: Umm, that seems to have linear complexity , i.e. Theta(value), rather than logarithmic, which is quite achievable, e.g. in @Linoliumz 's answer.

Answer (score 15):

Below is a constexpr square root implementation that uses binary search. It works correctly up to 2^64 with gcc and clang, other simpler versions often fail for numbers > 2^32 because compilers limit the recursion depth to e.g. 200.

```
// C++11 compile time square root using binary search

#define MID ((lo + hi + 1) / 2)

constexpr uint64_t sqrt_helper(uint64_t x, uint64_t lo, uint64_t hi)
{
  return lo == hi ? lo : ((x / MID < MID)
      ? sqrt_helper(x, lo, MID - 1) : sqrt_helper(x, MID, hi));
}

constexpr uint64_t ct_sqrt(uint64_t x)
{
  return sqrt_helper(x, 0, x / 2 + 1);
}
```

Below is a nicer version (for integer constants) which requires C++14, it is similar to the one presented in Baptiste Wicht's [blog post](http://baptiste-wicht.com/posts/2014/07/compile-integer-square-roots-at-compile-time-in-cpp.html). C++14 constexpr functions are allowed to use local variables and if statements.

```
// C++14 compile time square root using binary search

template <typename T>
constexpr T sqrt_helper(T x, T lo, T hi)
{
  if (lo == hi)
    return lo;

  const T mid = (lo + hi + 1) / 2;

  if (x / mid < mid)
    return sqrt_helper<T>(x, lo, mid - 1);
  else
    return sqrt_helper(x, mid, hi);
}

template <typename T>
constexpr T ct_sqrt(T x)
{
  return sqrt_helper<T>(x, 0, x / 2 + 1);
}
```

Comment: Why is `MID` a macro?

Comment: Because in C++11 static const variables inside constexpr functions are not allowed.

Comment: Is this for show, or do people really use something that takes over 200 recursions to compile?

Comment: @Mikhail: This version doesn't take 200 recursions. AraK's does. This version just takes about `log_2(x)` iterations, which is pretty reasonable.

Comment: I use in my program to calculate the square root of std::numeric_limits<T>::max() at compile time, T can be int32_t, int64_t, __int128_t or __uint128_t which uses up to 128 recursions.

Comment: A `static` variable could also be harmful, since this function can be called by multiple threads concurrently at runtime. But why not `constexpr uint64_t mid(uint64_t lo, uint64_t hi) { return (lo + hi + uint64_t(1)) / uint64_t(2); }`? You could compute this once and pass `lo`, `hi` and the result of `mid` to a `sqrt_helper2`, although that could double the amount of recursions.

Comment: It is even possible to use up only one more level of recursion and make `mid` a function: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f6e2be98d2c2aed6

Comment: This only works for integers, right? The answer is unclear on that... if it's true, there should probably some enable_if machinery to forbid specialization for real numbers.

Answer (score 13):

There is now a proposal [P1383R0 More constexpr for `<cmath>` and `<complex>` (Edward J. Rosten, Oliver J. Rosten)](https://github.com/cplusplus/papers/issues/168) which unfortunately hasn't gotten into C++20 and from the latest comment may not be in C++23 either. C++26?

Answer (score 10):

If we look at the closest draft standard to C++11 [N3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) we can see that `sqrt` is not marked *constexpr*, from section `26.8` *c.math*:

> The contents of these headers are the same as the Standard C library
>   headers  and  respectively, with the following
>   changes:

none of the changes include adding *constexpr* to `sqrt`.

We can see from the question [Is gcc considering builtins of non-constant expression functions to be constant expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22182432/1708801), that `gcc` marks many math functions as *constexpr* as an extension. This extension is a [non-conforming extension](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27744079/1708801), as I note in my answer to the linked question when `gcc` implemented this it looked like it would be a conforming extension but this changed and `gcc` is likely to fix this this extension to be conforming.