# constexpr math functions in C++20

Tags: c++, templates, constexpr, c++20

I am trying to do something like:

```
#include <cmath>

template <unsigned A, unsigned B>
struct fu {
    constexpr unsigned long power_A_of_B = std::pow(A, B);
};
```

But the compiler gives error because `pow()` is not `constexpr`.

Why are math functions in header `<cmath>` not `constexpr`?
For example, `log()`, `log2()`, `pow()`, `abs()` and `fmax()` are not `constexpr` but others in `<algorithm>` are, such as `max()`, `min()` and `clamp()'.

Comment: u can make yours

Comment: `std::is_constant_evaluated` to do it yourself :)

Comment: The answer is not some deep technical reason, just that "the committee are only human, they didn't get to it yet". Not sure of the current state of [these proposals](https://deathandthepenguinblog.wordpress.com/2019/02/17/more-constexpr-in-c20/).

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Constexpr Math Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17347935/1782792). In short, many `cmath` functions set `errno`, which is a side effect and therefore non constexpr.

Answer (score 3):

> Why are math functions in header  not constexpr?

Reason is well hidden in documentation of `std::pow`:

[std::pow, std::powf, std::powl - cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow)

> #### Error handling
>
> Errors are reported as specified in math_errhandling.

See documentation of [math_errhandling](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/math_errhandling).

Now how this macro could be handled in a `constexpr`?

So whole problem is maintaining compatibility with old specification.

The only possible solution is used alternative implementations. I've found [something like this](https://github.com/bolero-MURAKAMI/Sprout/tree/master/sprout/math), didn't tested it, but looks promising. Found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53141350/1387438).

Comment: Jammer. Thank you.