# Is this constexpr sqrt function portable?

Tags: c++, sqrt

I wrote this implementation of sqrt that is finite in complexity and precise up to the last digit when double is ieee754 double. The question is that is this portable on devices of various endian (assuming 0LL is still 64 bit)? get_fraction returns the 52bits plus the 1 bit at the begining. Small doubles are treated separately and ensured that they also have 1 in the 53rd bit. The c++ part `numeric_limits` nan can easily be replaced with a constant.

Code:

```
static inline constexpr int16_t get_exponent(double x)
{
    uint64_t bits = *(uint64_t*)&x;
    int16_t val = ((bits & 0x7FF0000000000000ULL) >> 52) - 1023;
    if(val != -1023)
        return val;
    uint64_t temp_fractal= (bits & 0x000FFFFFFFFFFFFFULL);
    for (int i = 51; i >= 0;--i) {
        if(!(temp_fractal & (0x01ULL<<i))) --val;
        else break;
    }
    return val;
}

static inline constexpr uint64_t get_fraction(double x)
{
    uint64_t bits = *(uint64_t*)&x;
    if (bits & 0x7FF0000000000000ULL)
        return (bits & 0x000FFFFFFFFFFFFFULL) | 0x0010000000000000ULL;
    uint64_t temp_fraction = bits & 0x000FFFFFFFFFFFFFULL;
    for (int i = 51; i >= 0; --i) {
        temp_fraction<<=1;
        if(0x0010000000000000ULL & temp_fraction) break;
    }
    return temp_fraction;
}

static inline constexpr bool is_reserved(double x)
{
    return get_exponent(x) == 1024;
}

static inline constexpr double my_abs(double x)
{
    uint64_t bits = *(uint64_t*)&x;
    bits &= 0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFULL;
    return *(double*)&bits;
}

constexpr double make_double(bool sign, int16_t exponent, uint64_t fractal)
{
    uint64_t data = (fractal & 0x000FFFFFFFFFFFFFULL);
    assert((fractal & 0xFFF0000000000000ULL) == 0x0010000000000000ULL);
    if (exponent < -1023) {
        fractal >>= (-1022 - exponent);
        data = fractal;
        exponent = -1023;   
    }
    else if (exponent > 1023) {
        return (1-2*sign)*std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity();
    }
    {
        data |= ((uint64_t)((uint16_t)(exponent + 1023))) << 52;
        if (sign)
            data |= 0x8000000000000000ULL;
        return *(double*)&data;
    }

}

constexpr double my_sqrt(double x)
{
    if(!x || is_reserved(x))
        return x;
    if(x < 0)
        return -std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN();
    uint64_t fraction = get_fraction(x);
    int16_t exponent = get_exponent(x);
    //C standard says it rounds to zero
    int16_t half_exponent = ((exponent-1024)/2)+512;
    uint64_t test_fraction = 0x0010000000000000ULL;
    double test = make_double(0, half_exponent, test_fraction);
    if (test * test > x) half_exponent -= 1;
    //just to be safe
    test = make_double(0, half_exponent, test_fraction);
    if (test * test > x) half_exponent -= 1;
    //find each bit except last one, binary search for result
    for (int i = 51; i > 0; --i) {
        test = make_double(0, half_exponent, test_fraction | (0x01ULL<<i));
        if(test*test<x) test_fraction |= (0x01ULL << i);
    }
    double del1 = my_abs(x - test*test);
    double temp = make_double(0, half_exponent, test_fraction | 0x01ULL);
    double del2 = my_abs(x - temp * temp);
    //see if the whole fraction needs to round up by one
    if (x > temp * temp) {
        test_fraction += 2;
        //rounding up by one made the fraction too large
        if (test_fraction >= 0x0020000000000000ULL) {
            test_fraction >>= 1;
            half_exponent -= 1;
        }
        double temp2 = make_double(0, half_exponent, test_fraction);
        double del3 = my_abs(x - temp2 * temp2);
        if(del3 <del2) return temp2;
        else return temp;
    }
    else if(del2<del1) return temp;
    else return make_double(0, half_exponent, test_fraction);
}
```

Edit: add some comments
Edit2: add missing functions

Comment: [Topic on constexpr sqrt()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8622256/in-c11-is-sqrt-defined-as-constexpr)

Comment: _"...is this portable ..."_:  code like `uint64_t bits = *(uint64_t*)&x;` (where `x` is `double`)  is Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: @RichardCritten even when double is ieee754 double which is required to be 64 bit?

Comment: This section applies as the C-style cast is equivalent to `reinterpret_cast` in this case _"Whenever an attempt is made to read or modify the stored value of an object of type DynamicType through a glvalue of type AliasedType, the behavior is undefined unless one of the following is true:"_  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast  And the code in this case does not fall into one of the allowed expressions.

Comment: Use `std::bit_cast` to avoid UB (and be constexpr-compatible).

Comment: @RichardCritten does this mean that casting pointers of different types will change the pointer contents, for example different types have to live in different parts of memory? It seems the docs are trying to keep that. In C it seems you don't care about pointer types as long as it's data on your heap?

Comment: @DavisHerring That's very nice to have. I didn't know that existed.

Comment: @DavisHerring But checking on the standard it seems that it requires c++20, which does not have much support yet. I guess I'll have to stick with the current stuff and implement this as my own temporary bit_cast for now.

Comment: @shangjiaxuan: The UB, as always, means anything whatsoever can happen—often because the compiler transformed the program during optimization into a form that is equivalent when UB does not occur but very different when it does.

Comment: @shangjiaxuan It means that trying to reason about portability is pointless until the UB is removed.  Either by modifying the code (usually to `std::memcpy`) or by linking to your compiler documentation where it may be a documented extension that we can all read.

Comment: @RichardCritten I can't use memcpy since it's not constexpr and rely on a compiler extension that is more specific than constexpr sqrt itself. Pointer casting of different types are supposed to be defined behavior in pure C, while c++ seems to add the classes and multiple inheritance which broke many things. The problem is that is there any existing compiler that breaks this for simple data types like double and 64 bit integer? For example an implementation that doesn't back the double in memory and only stores it in the register?

Comment: @shangjiaxuan Your question is only tagged [C++] (not [C]) and unless you link to your specific compiler extension documentation we have to refer to the Standard C++ when we answer.